# Deployment successful appears in Visual Studio, but Deployment Status "Not Deployed" appears in Solution Management

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

In Vısual Studio, the website is opening and "deploy succeed " appears. But i check my changes on the website, i saw there is no change. And i chaeck this situation from Solution Management from Central Admin. i saw the Deployment Status is "Not Deployed"

Answer (score 0):

Have you Retracted the wsp in Solution Management, if done, then the status will be Not deployed.

You can click Deploy Solution to redeploy the wsp solution:

[image]